# json_decode() is not working correctly

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here I am using simple html+jquery+ajax file 
the ajax code is here

```
var email = "am3042208007@gmail.com";
var username = "ankur_07";
var password = "pass07";
var phone_no = "7676715797";
var datastring = {
    "email": email,
    "username": username,
    "password": password,
    "phone_no": phone_no
};

            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "../test/testreg.php",
                data: {datastring : JSON.stringify(datastring)}, //with the page number as a parameter
                dataType: 'html', //expect html to be returned
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    /*if(data=="hello"){
                        message = "Mail Sent Successfully";
                    } else {
                        message = "Oops, mail doesn't send.!!!";
                    }
                    alert(message);*/
                }
            });
            return false;
```

I am sending json from this file and ant to get in another `testreg.php` file 
but it is not decoding json its showing as below line using in `echo`
`{\"email\":\"am3042208007@gmail.com\",\"username\":\"ankur_07\",\"password\":\"pass07\",\"phone_no\":\"7676715797\"}`

```
if(isset($_POST['datastring']))
{
           $data = $_POST['datastring'];
           $data = json_decode($data);

           print_r($data);
   }
```

please help me out of this stuck..

Comment: Check json error If any using function `json_last_error();` after json_decode.

Comment: Possibly [Magic Quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)?!

Comment: @Rikesh where we find error by json_last_error();

Comment: @deceze how to remove magic code

Comment: Hello everyone i have set `json_last_error();` but its shows error like
`- Syntax error, malformed JSON`

Comment: The error is in the JS and before the HTTP request and not in the PHP, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
data: {datastring : JSON.stringify(datastring)},
```

by

```
data: {datastring : datastring},
```

Explanation:

You are not sending JSON. You send an escaped string (removed JSON formatting) because you use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: can you please give me what is correct way to replace this one

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass json to php file.??? please i am not blaming you but want to learn more so please...

Comment: remove the `JSON.stringify`, see my answer to replace line

Comment: this showing me `Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /.../public_html/test/testreg.php on line 18`

Comment: What's wrong with you? DON'T use stripslashes. Slashes, quotes and escaped chars are there for a reason. They improve security, don't strip them without thinking.

Comment: You already have the solution using my answer: `parameter 1 to be string, array given` <---- this is your post'ed data as an array, as it should be, without stripsecurity() ........

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43249/discussion-between-scientist-and-danfromgermany)

Comment: You already proved that it's working for you but you don't understand? I don't have time for this, I'm not a teacher

Comment: but you already gives me solution very nicely..Thanks
CAN you see this chat

Comment: Yes, appreciated. If you have another question, [try this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you expect the result as php associative array by chance? Didn't you forget to supply second parameter (true) in [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) function? Since if you did, json_decode would return the result as object.

Answer (score -1):

You have to strip the slashes `\` from the post data and decode the json.

Please try using this

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($data), true);
```

**Note:** Please make sure that in this case `stripslashes()` will also remove your escaped sequence.

Comment: This is a nasty workarround and not a good solution because you strip slashes you need and you strip slashes from escaped chars you WANT to have. How can you accept this answer... how can someone give such bad advice..